# Need help in usage of Single Page Application through kendo UI

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application

We have started a new project and are thinking about which technology is suitable.  Below are the project details:

1. The application will be designed for HR Employees within the organization.  It includes some CRUD operations for dictionaries, i.e. master tables (10 tables).
2. The flow should be that the user will first see the list of master table records (they can search also), after that they are able to add/update/delete.

Finally the project should be responsive for all devices, Mobile, Tablet & Desktop, and the user experience should be acceptable.

Is there any problem with using a Single-Page Application paradigm with Web Api and Kendo Client Templates?

Also, can you provide samples of using SPA (CRUD operations)?

Answer (score 0):

Use EntitySetApiController instead of ApiController class to have good support of OData, specially when you are working with kendo components , lots of kendo samples are working with wcf data services and OData
Otherwise you'll have a problem in OData ($batch , $select , $callback , ...)